# Getting Error can't find '__main__' module in 'X'

Tags: python, module

I made a simple hello program using Sublime Text. Run it using windows powershell but everytime I am getting error like :

```
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'X'
```

X is the name of folder. I have Python 2.7.4 Installed. How to fix it?

Comment: You're running it how?

Comment: Cnn you copy/paste the traceback?  I'm gussing you're using `__main__` instead of `'__main__'` or something similar.

Comment: I am sorry I did not understand traceback?

Comment: @user1916876 -- The traceback is the information that python spits out when there's an Exception thrown.  you've paraphrased the last line above with `"C:\Python27\python.exe: can't find '_main_' module in 'X'"`

Comment: @mgilson C:\Python27\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'X'

Comment: @user1916876 -- There should be more to it than that.  It should tell you the line number where the error occurred for example.  It should also tell you the Exception *type* (e.g. `NameError` or `TypeError` ...)

Comment: Please post your source code.

Comment: @mgilson The problem is when I try to save my program in a folder(C:\Users\John)it shows that module error but when I save it in C:\Users It runs successfully.

Comment: @mgilson is this the problem of Adminstrative rights or Enviroment variables?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's something wrong with your `C:\Python27\python.exe`.

See if there are two **python** under the folder `C:\Python27`:

- python.exe
- python2.7.exe.

If so, chose the `python2.7.exe`

Also possible if your module X is in **anaconda** or something similar, then you should adjust your Sublime environment to include anaconda (or whatever you're using).

> Tools -> Build System -> New Build System

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about Python, other than running other people's Python apps on Windows occasionally.  I see that this is an old thread, but still ran into this just now--the app threw this error and wouldn't run at all unless I included the '.py' extension on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused by file corruption -- check that your module 'X' was copied correctly to the destination folder -- try opening it in an editor and make sure it looks ok. You will get this same error if you try to run Python on a file which is not a text file or a precompiled python module.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is the same what I get last night, if you are using PyCharm to code Python, you can re-check the existing configuration, make sure in the working directory section it is filled in, and in the script path section, it is the same as the file location and file name.
Actually this is a problem where you have to write down the correct storage place.